# How to create shortcuts from other android apps

Tags: android, android-intent

I am looking for a way to create shortcuts **from** other apps.
Like launchs can query the apps that allow to create shortcuts and create them save them in thier program.

My API version is between M(21) to N7.1(25).

Even just a link or name of API it's fine. I just couldn't find it at all. All I found is about the **new shortcut** in android N.

Thx for ur time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the way to do it. Since i don't see much info for this. I hope my share can help whoever is also looking for the answer.

So there will be 3 steps:

1. Get apps that can create shortcuts
2. Send `Intent` to the app that you want to create shortcut from
3. Get shortcut data in `Activity.onActivityResult`

**1.**
Since I just need to create shortcuts from certain apps. I skipped step one. But I guess using [**queryIntentActivities(...)**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#queryIntentActivities(android.content.Intent,%20int)) or some other functions in [PackageManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html) can get you the list.

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.CREATE_SHORTCUT");
PackageManager.queryIntentActitvies(intent,0);
```

**2.** Send intent to the app to create a shortcut.

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.CREATE_SHORTCUT");
intent.setComponent(...);
startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
```

**3.** Get data of shortcut:

1. Shortcut intent

`Intent shortcutIntent = activityResultIntent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT);`

2. Shortcut name

`String shortcutName = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME);`

3. Shortcut icon

`Bitmap shortcutIcon = intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON);`